# Establish persistent IP connection between docker containers

Tags: docker, cloud, containers, orchestration

I have multiple docker containers they need to be communicating with each other in a way that when a container is set to have an ip address, this ip address does not change after rebooting the container.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to establish inter-container communication is by creating a [networking bridge](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/).

1. Create a bridge

`docker network create <network-name>`

Ex: `docker network create my-net`

2. Create the containers linked to the bridge previously created.

`docker run --name <container-name> --network <network-name> <image>`

Ex: 
`docker run -d --rm --name my-bb1 --network my-net nginx:alpine
docker run -d --rm --name my-bb2 --network my-net nginx:alpine`

3. Access my-bb1 from my-bb2

`docker exec my-bb2 ping my-bb1
PING my-bb1 (172.18.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.18.0.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.165 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.3: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.184 ms
^C`

The container names will be persisted between reboots. So as long as the container names don't change, you'll be able to access them within the same container network.

I also highly recommend using [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) when there is more than one container involved.